# How to avoid overlapping of left and right thumb in crystalrangeseekbar when the range is higher

Tags: android, rangeseekbar

I am using Crystal range seekbar from https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar

I am sending the range dynamically. So when the range is high and I drag the thumbs, it overlaps since the gap calculation is too small and it gets overlapped. Is there a way to fix this issue ?

Comment: Anyone who was able to fix this thumb overlapping issue ? Really need help on this.

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue ? @Anji

Comment: Not yet... I tried with so many ways but still the issue is not resolved.